# Multiple grouping/sorting in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table with three fields: username, postName, post. How do I first group by postName and then group by username. So for example, I have 4 rows in my table:

1. username1, Convo1, My First Post
2. username1, Convo1, My Second Post
3. username2, Convo1, My First Post
4. username3, Convo2, My First Post

How do I group the Convo1's together (total count of 3) and then group the username together (so the count goes to 2 since rows 1 and 2 have the same username). Is there a way to do this with one query?

Comment: Did you try `SELECT ... GROUP BY postName, username` ?

Comment: Edit your question and provide more detail on the results that you want to get.

Comment: what is the desired output? (postname, username, count)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below should do it.  (Substitute whateverTableName, of course.)

```
SELECT postName, count(*) uniqueUsers
FROM
(  SELECT username, postName, count(*)
   FROM whateverTableName
   GROUP BY username, postName ) subqry1
GROUP BY postName
```

Sample output:

```
postName uniqueUsers
-------- -----------
Convo1             2
Convo2             1
```

The same solution, but as a pair of views, for use in frameworks that don't like using complex queries:

```
CREATE VIEW convo_by_user_post
AS
SELECT username, postName, count(*)
   FROM whateverTableName
   GROUP BY username, postName;

CREATE VIEW convo_unique_users
AS
SELECT postName, count(*) uniqueUsers
FROM convo_by_user_post
GROUP BY postName;
```

Then from your application:

```
SELECT postName, uniqueUsers FROM convo_unique_users
```

Comment: do you happen to know the php zend framework syntax for this?

Comment: If this query is not easily done in your framework (zend), consider saving this query in the database as a view, then your application side code is just a simple select from that view.